# .plist how to read dict in dict

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, filter, nsdictionary

I have a plist, and in my plist is a dictionary whose values are dictionaries, like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>Antenne Bayern</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shortcut</key>
        <true/>
        <key>url</key>
        <string>http://www.antenne.de/webradio/antenne-aac.pls</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Technobase.fm</key>
    <dict>
        <key>url</key>
        <string>http://listen.technobase.fm/tunein-aacplus-pls</string>
        <key>shortcut</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Now I wanna only read the url the key "Antenne Bayern" if in it's dictionary is "shortcut = 1"
I do it like this:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SenderDatabase" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *senderDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSDictionary *bli = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:senderDictionary] valueForKey:@"Antenne Bayern"];
NSLog(@"%@", bli);
NSString *check = [bli valueForKeyPath:@"shortcut"];
```

But I don't want to do that for every Item in the dictionary. I only want to return the name like "Antenne Bayern" if "shortcut = 1".
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to filter the keys of the dictionary based on a test of the associated values. Use `keysOfEntriesPassingTest:` to do this. You write the test to check the value of `shortcut`.

Aside:

In this line:

```
[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:senderDictionary] valueForKey:@"Antenne Bayern"];
```

the `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:senderDictionary]` should be replaced simply by `senderDictionary` because creating a new dictionary that will be destroyed again almost immediately is pointless.